# Where is a log file of passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, nginx, passenger

My rails application doesn't response for the address I configured in nginx (`No data response. Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)`). Now I'm trying to figure out what the problem could be. Nginx log has per request:

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
2013/10/21 15:15:30 [alert] 54636#0: worker process 54723 exited on signal 6

If I look into application log - there is no changes, looks, like passenger didn't request something from the app. So I though about another log files, where I could gather some information.

Where does passenger locate its log file?

Is there any special? 
Or does passenger use one of the application logs?

Answer (score 17):

In Linux, you can find your log files under

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: I had to restart my Ubuntu server before I could actually see what Passenger was writing to these files, FWIW...

Answer (score 2):

i got passenger error log from  `/tmp` folder(error log in .html format), and i used `scp` command to copy to my local machine from server

Comment: Thank you. This helped me find my passenger-error.html file that had the log message I needed to view.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, just for the records:

> By default Passenger log messages are written to the Nginx global error log.

This exert comes from a recent version. It may not apply before [Passenger 5.0.5](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_log_file).

Comment: This is totally applicable to versions before 5.0.5. It is applicable to all versions.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger prints its own logs not only to the terminal, but also to a log file. During startup, Passenger tells you what log file it used. This is typically log/passenger.XXXX.log.
see

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/quickstart/ruby/

mine was[3000 was port number for the app]  `less {app_dir}/log/passenger.3000.log`

if the passenger crashes, it shows on the console & passenger.xxxx.log the directory where the log files are

`[ pid=2659 ] Crash log files will be dumped to /var/tmp/passenger-crash-log.1583439070.ZfMXhF <--- ******* LOOK HERE FOR DETAILS!!! *******`